# SyntaxError: Unexpected token . JSON.stringify(database_params)

Tags: json, node.js

if i start my node application i get a syntax error. But why, after i using jshint, he check my code and show me error in JSON.stringify. I tried to fix this with this way JSON:stringify ,but code not work again. Do you know some method for fix this and why JSON.stringify is not correctly syntax.

```
function updateMarketPrices() {

    // BITSKINS API REQUEST FRESH PRICES
    request('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_all_item_prices/?api_key='+ API_KEYBIT+'&code='+bit_code+'', function(error, response, body) {
    prices = JSON.parse(body);

    if(prices.status != "success") {
        logger.warn('Loaded fresh prices');
        // CHANGE SITE LOCATION
        if(fs.existsSync('prices.txt')){
            // CHANGE SITE LOCATION
            prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('prices.txt'));
            logger.warn('Prices loaded from cache');
        } else {
            logger.error('No prices in cache');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    } else {

        var newprice = JSON.parse('{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1464567644,"items":{}}}');

        prices.prices.forEach(function(item) {
            newprice.response.items['migration_time_validation'] = {JSON.stringify(database_params)};   
            newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
                "value": item.price*1000
            }
        });

        // CHANGE SITE LOCATION
        fs.writeFileSync('prices.txt', JSON.stringify(newprice));
        logger.trace('New prices loaded');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are trying to use JSON.stringify() inside an object declaration in your foreach loop.

Call the JSON.stringify method outside of the object declaration, assign it to a variable, and use this instead.

Your code should end up something like this:

```
prices.prices.forEach(function (item) {
    var dbParams = JSON.stringify(database_params);

    newprice.response.items['migration_time_validation'] = { 
        dbParams
    };
    newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
        "value": item.price * 1000
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you just want to insert the JSON to the database, without wrapping it in a JavaScript object, just remove the braces as follows:

```
prices.prices.forEach(function (item) {
    newprice.response.items['migration_time_validation'] = JSON.stringify(database_params);

    newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
        "value": item.price * 1000
    }
});
```